# How do you make a variable comparison to decide a better score in a dice game?

Tags: python

So I am making a python file that creates a dice game. It holds 5 rounds for the 2 players and accumulates their scores at the end of each round. When the round ends their final scores are printed and the winner declared. I am having trouble when trying to make a bonus roll if the scores are tied, which will repeat until one player wins. I've set a variable player1F and player2F. I have used the if function to print who is the winner depending on who scores higher.

```
if overallp1==overallp2:
    roll=random.randint(1,6)
    player1F=(roll)


if player1F>player2F:
    print(player1 + ' IS THE WINNER ')

elif player1F<player2F:
    print(player2 + ' IS THE WINNER ')
```

Every time I run the program an error occurs saying that the player1F variable is not defined. Player1F is meant to exclusively be the total for the final round, so just the one score determines the win if there is a tie. However it is saying that it is not defined

Comment: And the question is??????
Please state what have you tried, how your code looks like, why it does not work, the expected behaviour and the unexpected behaviour etc so that someone can help

Comment: Edit your question by cutting and pasting your code into the question. Then highlight the code and click on the `{}` button.

Comment: You need to be very specific in your question. What does `I am having trouble making the program understand the player1F variable` mean?

Comment: If `player1F` is player 1 score, then you should probably put `player1F = 0` at the start of the game.

Comment: Somewhere before your `if` statements you need to set `player1F` to some value. Perhaps the indentation of the code in your question is incorrect. Should the `if/elif` block be inside the `if overallp1==overallp2:` block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, here is a way to accomplish what you want:

```
if overallp1==overallp2:
    player1F = 0
    player2F = 0
    while player1F == player2F:
        player1F=random.randint(1,6)
        player2F=random.randint(1,6)

    if player1F>player2F:
        print(player1 + ' IS THE WINNER ')

    elif player1F<player2F:
        print(player2 + ' IS THE WINNER ')
```

Also, the final `elif` can be just `else`, since there are no other possibilities at that point.

Comment: For some reason it is still coming up with an error claiming:                   if player1F>player2F:
NameError: name 'player1F' is not defined                                        This is occurring further down the code even though it is already set the value 0

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, I can only guess that you have a `scope` issue. Have a look at [scope documentation](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html#variable-scope-and-lifetime)